# After contact form 7 mail sent need to submit another hidden form

Tags: wordpress

I have a form made by contact form 7. After the form data successfully sent i need to submit another hidden form to external CRM. My code is below

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' ); 
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {
$title = $contact_form->id;
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
}
if ( 12 == $title ) {
$firstname = $posted_data['firstname'];
echo '<form name="bntWebForm" id="bntWebForm" method="post"action="https://www.bntouchmortgage.net/account5/webform/" style="display:none;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name_1" value="'.$firstname.'" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> ';
?>
<script>document.getElementById("bntWebForm").submit();</script>
<?php 
}
}
```

But whenever i ran the code it is not working and the ajax loaded endlessly spining. Can anyone please help me how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is basically incorrect.

The `wpcf7_mail_sent` action occurred in the server side and it cannot be used to add DOM element to the page. The form you try to echo out together with the javascript code will never be added to the page and run on the client side environment you're expecting.

To send a post with data to the external endpoint you want, you can still use the `wpcf7_mail_sent` hook using PHP curl functions to send a HTTP post request.

An example can be found below:

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function() {
   $endpoint_url = 'https://www.bntouchmortgage.net/account5/webform/';
   $data_to_post = ['name_1' => $firstname];

   // Sets our options array so we can assign them all at once
   $options = [
       CURLOPT_URL        => $endpoint_url,
       CURLOPT_POST       => true,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_to_post,
   ];

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

   // Executes the cURL POST
   $results = curl_exec($curl);

   curl_close($curl);
});
```